# How do I evaluate the line $\int F \cdot dr$ when $F = (5xy^3)i + (3x^2y^2)j$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

On the curve C consisting of the x-axis from x=0 to x=4, the parabola $y=16−x^2$ up to the y-axis, and the y-axis down to the origin.

I can't seem to get the right answer. Since the vector field is not conservative, I'll just have to integrate each individual part of the curve. However, the force is 0 along the x and y axes, so I just have to integrate along the parabola y = 16 - x^2 right?

So I'm evaluating $\int_{0}^{1} 80t(16-16t^2)^3-1536t^3(16-16t^2)^2dt$

I've simplified it a little.

But I don't know why this keeps giving me the wrong answer?

Comment: You parametrized the parabolic path in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using,

$$\int_C \vec{F}(x,y)\cdot d\vec{r} = \int_a^b \vec{F}(\vec{r}(t))\cdot \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} dt$$

let's parametrize the parabolic path as $\vec{r}(t)=\langle t,16-t^2\rangle$ where $4\ge t \ge 0$. Note that $t$ must run backwards from $4$ to $0$, since after the first horizontal path, the particle is at $x=4$. Then,

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_C\langle5xy^3,\ \ 3x^2y^2\rangle \cdot  d\vec{r} \\ \\
&= \int_4^0\langle 5t(16-t^2)^3,\ \ 3t^2(16-t^2)^2\rangle \cdot  \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} dt \\ \\
&= \int_4^0 \langle 5t(16-t^2)^3,\ \ 3t^2(16-t^2)^2\rangle \cdot \langle 1,-2t\rangle \ dt\\ \\
&= \int_4^0 5t(16-t^2)^3-6t^3(16-t^2)^2\ dt\\ \\
&= -24576\\ \\
\end{align*}$$

---

PS. From the looks of things, I think your parametrization may have been $\vec{r}(u)=\langle 4u,16-(4u)^2\rangle$ for $0\ge u \ge 1$. The only thing that's off is the direction that $u$ runs. The parametrization that I used just has $t=4u$.